# make increment_id of an order syncron to external system

Tags: orders, sales-order, increment-id

We are integrating Magento with an existing system. Our existing system already has order numbers. There has been a lot of confusion since Magento has its own order numbers, and our existing system has different order numbers, so we're trying to get the order numbers to match up.

I have an observer set up for sales_order_place_after where I get the order number from our existing system. It doesn't seem to work to $order->setIncrementId($our_existing_order_id) I don't know if this is really all that good of an idea anyways..

Really, the end goal we want is for the order #s in email receipts that are sent out to match the order #s in our existing systems. Is there a better way to make that happen?

Comment: Are you just trying to change order increment id to match your system only once or do you need to get an order id from your existing system everytime (will your existing system continue to place orders along side magento)?

Comment: What is the format of the order numbers in the external system?

Comment: As long as you can handle the fact that Magento will preallocate order numbers during card submission and therefore will skip numbers on card decline. Magento will need the driver's seat on creating the SO number which then gets delivered to the ERP system.

Comment: @R.S I need it to continue to do this. Magento is just one of the ways we create orders in our system. We also have POS and salesmen, etc.

Comment: @JonathanHussey They are <branch number><increment order number> - So for one order might be 71352 then the next one might be 1132352. I thought about trying to keep them "synched", but that seems nearly impossible.

Comment: @FiascoLabs We really need Magento to match up with our other order #s, not the other way around. Magento is one small piece of a very, very large puzzle.

Comment: What I would recommend is to create a new field in sales_flat_order to store this id then update the different template as needed to display this number. This way you will have a clean upgrade path in the future

Comment: @R.S That's kind of the direction I was thinking we might need to go. I was hoping there might be an easier way, since there are a lot of places this increment_id is used.

Comment: Rarely is there an easy solution when Magento and ERP integration are mentioned in the same paragraph. Anything that has id_ in Magento pretty much needs to be left alone as it's a table key and having a field to hold the ERP generated SO number is the best way of handling it. Then show it in the grid on the backend and search/sort on it.

Comment: @R.S If you add your comment as an answer I will mark it is the accepted answer. That was what we ended up doing and it worked great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would recommend is to create a new field in sales_flat_order to store this id then update the different template as needed to display this number. This way you will have a clean upgrade path in the future

Answer (score 4):

One solution would be to create your own eav entity model. If you look in the `eav_entity_type` table in the column `increment_model` you see there is a class path there. Replace those with your own custom model, for example `[module]/entity_increment_erp`

```
class [Namespace]_[Model]_Model_Entity_Increment_Erp extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Abstract
{
    public function getNextId()
    {
        /**
        * your custom code to generate the increment ID, 
        * as long as it is unique
        */

        return $id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think @R.S suggestion will be good for him, rather than changing the way how Magento works it's better to connect his ERP order number with a custom field in order table.

Comment: Good point, hopefully he adds his comment as answer too :)